# Designing the interface for a function, force user(client) to provide memory region >= required size. How to, is it good or bad?

Tags: c++, dll, interface

I am designing **DLLs interface** and question arose while I was trying to provide interface for a function with the following functionality:
it accepts `char* inputData` encodes it and result is data of larger size `char* outPutdata` which it returns(using return statement or as additional parameter & in function) to the user.
I choose resource model where **client manages resources**(allocates, deallocates) and Dll works with them.

S**izeof input/output data is known and is fixed**.
In order for my library to work properly I need the client to allocate at least required number of bytes for inputData and outPutdata.

**Question consists of 2 parts:**
 1. What can you tell about such design, where client is forced to
    allocate given amount of memory, any proposals?
 2. How to force client to allocate certain amount of memory?

**For part 1**: I haven't found any resources, so links are welcomed
**For part 2:** I consider the following function:

```
bool/*isOK*/encode(uint8_t(&inData)[SOME_CONSTANT],uint8_t(&outData)[ANOTHER_CONSTANT])
```

Is it a good solution to pass array by reference, client can allocate memory and cast it to array and pass to the function.

What do you think, is that situation frequent when designing interfaces of libraries, can you propose libraries which I could use as an example/bench mark?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting and an important question.

> 1. What can you tell about such design, where client is forced to allocate given amount of memory, any proposals?

This is a common case where an API expects a pointer to a buffer allocated by the client/user. But the important part is making sure that, it must the code that allocated the buffer to deallocate as well.
A bad example for eg is: The library gives the client an allocated buffer. It must *always* be the library that should deallocate the buffer, client should not try to deallocate. This is because the library may have been compiled differently from the client and might be using a different allocator which the allocator at the client side might not understand and hence causing heap corruption. 
Same case vice-versa when client passes a buffer to library.

> 2. How to force client to allocate certain amount of memory?

This is what I have com up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>


static const size_t INPUT_ALLOC_SIZE = 1024;
static const size_t OUTPUT_ALLOC_SIZE = 1024 * 10;

template <size_t Size, typename Allocator>
struct Deletor {
  void operator()(typename Allocator::pointer ptr) {
    Allocator a;
    a.deallocate(ptr, Size);
  }
};

template <size_t Size, typename Allocator = std::allocator<char>>
struct AllocWrapper
{
  friend AllocWrapper<INPUT_ALLOC_SIZE> allocate_input_buffer();
  friend AllocWrapper<OUTPUT_ALLOC_SIZE> allocate_output_buffer();

  AllocWrapper(AllocWrapper&& other): buffer_(std::move(other.buffer_)) {}

private:
  AllocWrapper() {
    Allocator a;
    buffer_.reset(a.allocate(Size));
  }

  std::unique_ptr<typename Allocator::value_type[], Deletor<Size, Allocator>> buffer_ = nullptr;
};


AllocWrapper<INPUT_ALLOC_SIZE> allocate_input_buffer()
{
  return AllocWrapper<INPUT_ALLOC_SIZE>();
}
AllocWrapper<OUTPUT_ALLOC_SIZE> allocate_output_buffer()
{
  return AllocWrapper<OUTPUT_ALLOC_SIZE>();
}

template <size_t InSize, size_t OutSize, typename Allocator,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<(InSize == INPUT_ALLOC_SIZE) ||
                                             (OutSize == OUTPUT_ALLOC_SIZE)>::type>
bool encode(AllocWrapper<InSize, Allocator>& input,
      AllocWrapper<OutSize, Allocator>& output)
{
  return false;
}


int main() {
  auto i_buf = allocate_input_buffer();
  auto o_buf = allocate_output_buffer();
  encode(i_buf, o_buf);
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE::**
This is in no way how you should code it up for production purposes, but surely this is one step or two steps in the right direction. 
The buffer allocation or deallocation and how it needs to be done is completely under clients control AND also the API makes sure, the right type hence the right buffer size is being passed to it.

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to go through code snippets thoroughly in order to reply smth. At first glance: might usage of templates lead to that in client one version of code for allocator is instantiated and in library in the encode function another one and what might be consequences? Thank you for ideas.

Comment: @spin_eight No, encode takes the objects by reference, it does not or should not be having any need to instantiate any AllocWrapper object. Besides, the standard library takes an allocator like this in quite a lot of places.

Comment: I mean code instantiation for the template, I am speaking about code, not object

Comment: @spin_eight Oh..ok, for the code, I dont see that happening as well, since the input parameters provided are what given out by allocate_*_buffer functions.

Comment: @spin_eight Also, AllocWrapper cannot be instantiated by the client as it has private constructor.